# How to securely pass a string from a Webview Activity to a running Service in Android?

Tags: javascript, android, android-intent, webview, uri

In my app I want to pass a string from a WebView Activity, perhaps after a user submits a form, straight to my app's running service, which has its own process.

Hard mode: no malicious app should ever be able to intercept this string.

Is this possible at all? Any ideas?

Sorry, I'm kinda new to Android, so I'm not sure if I'm even making sense.  :'(

Heeeelp :-) :-)

Comment: **"...I'm not sure if I'm even making sense."** - Unfortunately, no offence, that is the case (partially at least). What is the source of the 'string'? What is the 'background process'? If you can expand on these things and what the purpose is then perhaps someone can help further.

Comment: By background process, I mean a Service running in its own process. (I will have that changed, sorry)

The source of the string will be from a form on the Webview activity. I want that string to be handed to my service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android (as in Linux), each app runs as a separate user, identified by a UID. Thus another app cannot generally get access you app's files or process(es). In short, you are OK without having to do anything special. If your service is exported (other apps can use it), you might want to use a signature permission or check the caller's UID to make sure only your WebView can call the service, and no other app can send you bogus data.

On a rooted device, if the user allows some app to get root access, it can dump memory, and basically do anything. Then it could read anything in memory, including your super-secret string. There is really no bullet-proof way to protect from this situation.

Comment: THANK YOU. I can't you rate up because I have no reputation. I always thought that in-memory storage of data is more secure than writing to disk (such as shared preferences or sqlite)... However, you mentioned that memory can be dumped in a rooted device... So I might as well just write the string straight to disk then, and have the service read it via polling. I guess the only solution is to warn the rooted users that they're in risk. Thanks.

Comment: Writing to disk is essentially the same: each app has its own files, and other apps cannot read (or write) time if you don't give explicit permission. On a rooted device if you grant some app root privileges, it will be able to read or write any file. BTW, you should be able to accept the answer, even if you can't rate it up.